# Bootstrap Carousel make 12th item active in Laravel Blade

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap carousel for displaying the month and year. I want to show the months and years over a period of 2 years. One year past from current month year and one future year from current month.

For current scenario i.e. from January 2018 to January 2020. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
    @for($i=-12;$i<=12;$i++)
    <div class="mySlides fade @if($i==0) {{'active'}} @endif" style="display: @if($i==0) {{'block'}} @endif;">
        <div class="numbertext" >{{ date('F - Y', strtotime('today -'.$i.'month')) }}</div>
    </div>
    @endfor
    <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
    <a class="prev"  onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    slides[i].classList.remove("active");  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  slides[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

</script>
```

HERE IS MY OUTPUT LOOKS LIKE (So that you can better understand my problem):
[image: Screenshot of my app]

As you can see in my code I tried to make slide with current month and year to be active and display block, but I am always getting "January 2020" selected.

Let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain the sequence ...January 2018 to January 2020... your loop is wrong. Change it from:

```
 @for($i=-12;$i<=12;$i++)
<div class="mySlides fade @if($i==0) {{'active'}} @endif" style="display: @if($i==0) {{'block'}} @endif;">
    <div class="numbertext" >{{ date('F - Y', strtotime('today -'.$i.'month')) }}</div>
</div>
@endfor
```

to:

```
@for($i=-12;$i<=12;$i++)
<div class="mySlides fade @if($i==0) {{'active'}} @endif" style="display: @if($i==0) {{'block'}} @endif;">
    <div class="numbertext" >{{ date('F - Y', strtotime('today +'.$i.'month')) }}</div>
</div>
@endfor
```

Use + instead of - in **strtotime**

Moreover, this style attribute is wrong:

```
@if($i==0) {{'block'}} @endif;"
```

use the else part in order to set **none**

In the following a snippet with a changed structure:

```css
#carousel-example {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 50px;
}
.numbertext {
    color:black;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>January - 2018</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>February - 2018</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>March - 2018</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>April - 2018</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>May - 2018</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>June - 2018</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>July - 2018</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>August - 2018</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>September - 2018</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>October - 2018</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>November - 2018</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>December - 2018</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>January - 2019</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item ">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>February - 2019</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>March - 2019</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>April - 2019</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>May - 2019</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>June - 2019</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>July - 2019</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>August - 2019</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>September - 2019</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>October - 2019</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>November - 2019</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>December - 2019</p></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="numbertext"><div><p>January - 2020</p></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I do the changes you said but nothing changes except, now I am getting January 2018 selected instead of January 2020.

Comment: @gaetnoM, Thanks again and I really appreciate your help, but I can't change it's HTML structure bcoz there is some other styles and script working on the same structure and I also tried with static content but still getting the first item selected.